# How to verify / store the babackground-color from the css file on Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Im want to verify / store the background color from the app-1450173274570.css file and want to check selected theme color is set properly.

That locator id (ember610') will change on every refresh

```html
<td>verifyAttribute</td>
<td>//div[@id='ember610']/div</td>
<td>*background-color= #ffffff*</td>
```

```css
.netplus body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: Do you have problem in identifying element because //div[@id keeps changes for every refresh? If so, then there should another node prior to it should have constant value. You can as that in your xpath to identify element.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically pull the value out of the css file? You've have to open that css file directly and figure out how to pull it out dynamically. Open can handle a full url.

Comment: @AbdulHameed - If i choose the xpath it is not identifying the element when i use the FIND from IDE. xpath=//body/div[3]/div/div .......                      [error] Element //body/div[3]/div/di not found